# Twitter api showing authantication error

Tags: android, twitter

i am integrating twitter with android it is showing the flowing errors please help to resolve the error

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

Comment: Do what the error says and use the new API.

Comment: sir i am doing that but.. there is no solution i have found on net if you have any solution please give... thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using twitter4j for authentication then use the latest twitter4j jar file from [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/) and replace it with the older one. I am sure it will definitely help you.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is easy if you just read the error.

**The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1**

What if you go to the club and you see a sign:

> "Our club has a new entrance and dress-code, please enter club at
>   other side of town."

They also provide a lot of maps, so you can find the way.

So instead of standing next to the sign saying

> "This club is BROKEN! How do I get in, what do I do!? Does someone have a MAP?"

Read the sign again and take one of their maps, read it and go to the new club. And have fun!

This has been known for a long time.

You will need to rewrite your communication with the twitter API according to it's documentation which can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

So read the documentation, adjust all your api calls. Make sure authorization is up to 1.1. and test. No tips and tricks, just plain ol' developing.

Here are other resources to help make this transition more smooth:

- [FAQ: What does API v1 Retirement entail?](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq/#17750)
- [API v1.1 Overview](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview)
- [Embedded Timelines Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+Twitter+REST+API+v1+is+no+longer+active.+Please+migrate+to+API+v1.1